# Jump to the next fragment on any fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter in my app.
this is my adapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    List<FeedItem> posts = FeedListFragment.getPosts();

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        FeedItem post = posts.get(position);
        String url = post.getUrl();
        String title = post.getTitle();
        String imagUrl = null;
        if (post.getType() == FeedItem.ARTICLE_VIEW_TYPE) {
            imagUrl = posts.get(position).getArticle().getImageUrl();
        }
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment(url, title, imagUrl);
        fragment.setPostsFragmentOnItemClickListener(PostActivity.this);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }
}
```

What I need is to jump to a specific position in this adapter and also the ability to jump to the next and prev view.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `viewPagerInstance.setCurrentItem(int position)`. Remember the position it is 0 based (you can use values between `0` and `adapter.getCount() - 1` ).

For the next and previuos item use :

```
int currentItem = pager.getCurrentItem();
```

and add `+/- 1` to `currentItem`. Of course you have to check if `currentItem+1` is not beyond `adapter.getCount()` and `if currentItem-1` is greather than or equal to 0

Edit: I used `mPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);` It works great.

Comment: Great!!  and how can I go to next and prev?

Comment: I used mPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT); for next. but Thanks!