# Fragment null pointer exception when using viewPagerInstance.setCurrentItem(int position)

Tags: android, fragment

I have 10 Fragment lists. I am able to swipe and update value of current Fragment. At top of each Fragment i have a list of number like page1, page2, page3...page15
so now i am also want to jump in clicked page fragment. so i am using

```
viewPagerInstance.setCurrentItem(int position)
```

it works if i jump left of right page of current page. but if i clicked on another page like as i am in page2 and want to go page10. it give me null pointer exception.
i got null error in my resources ( button). is onCreateView working correctly? because all resource has already initialized. so it should not be null.

please help expert

my adapter

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scorecardtabswingfragment,
            container, false);


    puttsBtnList = new ArrayList<Button>();
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn0));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn1));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn2));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn3));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn4));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn5));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn6));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn7));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn8));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn9));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn10));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn11));
    puttsBtnList.add((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.puttsBtn12));


    holeTitle = new TextView[18];
    holeTitle[0] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole1);
    holeTitle[1] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole2);
    holeTitle[2] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole3);
    holeTitle[3] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole4);
    holeTitle[4] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole5);
    holeTitle[5] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole6);
    holeTitle[6] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole7);
    holeTitle[7] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole8);
    holeTitle[8] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole9);
    holeTitle[9] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole10);
    holeTitle[10] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole11);
    holeTitle[11] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole12);
    holeTitle[12] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole13);
    holeTitle[13] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole14);
    holeTitle[14] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole15);      
    holeTitle[15] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole16);
    holeTitle[16] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole17);
    holeTitle[17] = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole18);

    for(ImageButton b: firBtnList) {
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    for(Button b: penaltyBtnList) {
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    for(Button b : puttsBtnList) {
        b.setOnClickListener(this); 
        }

    for(Button b : storksBtnList) {
    b.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    for(TextView tv : holeTitle) {
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    toggleBtnPlayed.setOnClickListener(this);
    //TextView tv_hole = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hole);
    //tv_hole.setText("Hole:"+getArguments().getInt("holeNum"));

    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {

            if(APIUtil.isNeedForUpdate) 
                //update hole Golfer Scorecard.
                new UpdateHoleGolferScorecard(APIUtil.holeno_Update, APIUtil.score_Update, 
                        APIUtil.fir_Update, APIUtil.gir_Update, APIUtil.played_Update, APIUtil.putts_Update).execute();

            getActivity().finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScorecardsActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);      
        }
    });

    swingBtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.swingBtn);
    swingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    return mView;
}
```

**update**

i am using **setMenuVisibility** of visible property. i think it is calling first and after that onActivityCreated(). I putt my all code into onActivityCreated() and working now. resource is initialized. but is it possible call

```
onActivityCreated first and after that setMenuVisibility. because for some reason i used it.
```

Comment: We need your source-code of `getItem()` in Adapter method and `onCreateView()` method of that Fragment.

Comment: @Geralt please check, i updated

Comment: Check this link. Here see Accept answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807555/jump-to-the-next-fragment-on-any-fragment-in-fragmentstatepageradapter

Comment: @JigarShekh i did , but working if i do click upto near 3 -4 pages. but if i clicked a pages who is so far of current page. giving null

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved my problem.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(17);
```

i loaded my all pages.

I am using setMenuVisibility() because i don't want to load previous and next page update. i want to load my current page only. so it called first when page changed.